# Slanted fractions in MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax

Are slanted fractions supported in MathJax?

None of the [tricks shown here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Fractions_and_Binomials) appear to work.

Comment: One of the tricks from your link: $${}^3/_7$$

Comment: That doesn't work if it appears after another term.  E.g., $$x {}^3_7$$

Comment: You seem to be missing a $/$, as in $x {}^3/_7$. To make the multiplication clear I might use `\cdot`, like $x \cdot {}^3/_7$

Comment: That does it: I wasn't adding the "/".  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This approach works best for me:

```
                    \stackrel{25}{}\!\!\unicode{x2215}_{\!\unicode{x202f}72}
```

$$\stackrel{25}{}\!\!\unicode{x2215}_{\!\unicode{x202f}72}$$

---

`\unicode{x2215}` represents a [$\,\underline{\verb|DIVISION SLASH|}$](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2215)

`\unicode{x202f}` represents a [$\,\underline{\verb|NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE|}$](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+202F)

Comment: I've mentioned this in comments below [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32660/284619).